# how to detect number gesture in android

Tags: android

I am trying to detect when a user draws a number on the screen, for example, number one can be translated as a top to down movement with a reasonable angle (+- 10 degrees on the y-axis), what I am doing is checking the direction of the motion and giving it an angle range to check the line within. this technique usually works for most digits.

for more complicated numbers I am dividing the resulting shape into lines based on the direction on movement, for example two is a result of the following lines:
- line with direction North east and an angle between 10 and 30 degrees with the x axis
- line with direction South east and an angle between -10 and -30 degrees with the x axis
....

Is there an easier way to do this, or maybe there is something already out there which do this :) , I am worried about checking errors in the motion that might happen and should be tolerated, such as unexpected slight finger movements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using the [android.gesture library](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html).  This lets you create a library of gestures as resources in your program, and provides the API for detecting the library of gestures.